# Material-UI Dialog style action button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to edit style of action button. Is it possible to access the div that contains the action buttons in a Dialog, DatePicker, or TimePicker?

I'm trying to add padding between these buttons. Unrelated, it would be nice if there was a way to access/style the div that is generated when these buttons are created to change background color. Currently if you change background color of body it does not cover the div where the buttons live.

P.S. I've also tried everything listed in the MUItheme api for TimePicker as well as all the props exposed in the docs.

```
styles = {
  textField: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif !important',
    fontWeight: 100,
  }
}

<TimePicker
  floatingLabelText="Start Time"
  floatingLabelStyle={this.styles.textField}
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give the buttons their own style properties:

```
buttonStyle: {
    margin: 6,
    backgroundColor: "#2b2b2b"
}
```